# problem whit Gradle in Flutter android studio 3.2 working behind a proxy

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, flutter

I'm working behind a proxy and i have this problem when i run muy flutter app in android studio 3.2

```
Launching lib\main.dart on LGMS323 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Finished with error: Exit code 1 from: D:\Android\Flutter\Mis_Proyectos\flutter_app\android\gradlew.bat -v:
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip   

Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:673)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1546)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

And when I change in android/gradle/wraper/gradle-graper.properitis:

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip

for

distributionUrl=D:\Android\Gradle/gradle-4.6-all.zip

this happens:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on LGMS323 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Finished with error: Exit code 1 from: D:\Android\Flutter\Mis_Proyectos\flutter_app22222222\android\gradlew.bat -v:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistName(PathAssembler.java:84)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistribution(PathAssembler.java:40)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

Comment: "java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org" :  it looks like you have some network issue: did you try to download the zip distribution directly from a web browser with  https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip   ?

Comment: Yes, I have gradle downloaded. I'm also working behind a proxy. but I do not know how to configure the gradle

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `android/gradle/wrapper/graddle-wrapper.properties` from

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
```

or alternatively

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

Comment: does it need to download gradle for each app i create, if so then why?

Comment: Different apps can depend on different Gradle versions. I don't remember more details. I have no good Gradle knowledge and it's a while I had to deal with that.

Answer (score 1):

Try with a file protocol URL for pointing to local file. Like this -

`distributionUrl=file:///D:/Android/Gradle/gradle-4.6-all.zip`

Although, you might face further proxy blockages (with dl.google.com etc.) if your company has any.

Comment: Right, although I got away with Gradle but stuck at other files

Answer (score 0):

Sometime problem in the local.properties file under android. like path of sdk is not properly declare so you must check it and if any error it show automatically.

Comment: This is more of a comment giving a general suggestion than a full answer. Take a look again at [answer]